# How to have an `auto fit content` textbox in Visio 2013?

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2013

For my drawings, I want the textbox(es) to be automatically resized to the text content. How can I get that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Open `Show ShapeSheet` for `Shape`
2. In `Shape Transform`, set **Width=TEXTWIDTH(TheText)** and **Height=TEXTHEIGHT(TheText, 999)**

Reference [here](http://visguy.com/vgforum/index.php?topic=1000.0).

[image]

[image]

Comment: The answer here is deceiving. The image with yellow highlight shows that the TEXTHEIGHT function's second argument should be 0.9 in when in fact it should be 999 as shown in the original answer. If you use 0.9, then the text box grows as you type text on a single line, causing spaces to form under that line of text.

Comment: Instances that are already on drawing don`t inherit new master formula. To update them it is necessary to use scripting or Cntr+X to get a master formula for some cell

Answer (score 1):

Steps to achieve auto-resize of a text box dependent on the containing text (in Visio Professional 2019):

1. Select the text box
2. Klick on `Developer`->`Show ShapeSheet`->`Shape`
   [(Edit Shape)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2X2Dh.png)
3. Add `=TEXTWIDTH(TheText)` to the **Width** field
4. Add `==TEXTHEIGHT(TheText,TxtWidth)` to the **Height** field
   [(Edit Height)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dT8eI.png)

*Note:* When missing the `Developer` section in the Ribbon in the top, right click on the ribbon and choose `Customize the Ribbon`
[(Customize Ribbon)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GtbR.png)
Then check the `Developer` section.
[(Check Developer section)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUxbD.png)

Sorry, I would have added the pictures directly, but this requires 10 reputations.

Answer (score 0):

To autoadjust the height of a visio (2016) box or text box, and leave the width as set:

(1) Click on the box, then menu selection: Developer > ShowShapeSheet

(2) Select 'Shape Transform' pane, in the Height enter '=TEXTHEIGHT(TheText,1.2)', then Enter.

This will adjust the box to fit the text height. This is not a perfect solution because sometimes the box will be slightly too small, in which case a workaround is to add a padding line break before or after the text.Alternatively change the 1.2 to say 1, though this will sometimes make the box too big.

Changing the font size will cause the box to adjust accordingly.