# Creating Visio object with auto-height Header and Body text boxes

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2013

I wish to create an Object* that has Header and Body text boxes that auto-height with text but allow horizontal manual resizing.

I have created this visual (using grouped shapes and manual grouping/ungrouping/regrouping before resizing = yuk!!!) to better illustrate what I am trying to do. Please see for reference numbers:

1.1.1 = Default object appearance (single line of text) and overall object handles.
1.2.1 = Showing the body area auto-height resizing with additional lines of text.
1.3.1 = Same as 1.2.1 but with additional lines added to the Header and Body area.

1.1.2 = 1.1.1 if the object is widened by dragging handles (text reflows and height auto adjusts).
1.2.2 = 1.2.1 if the object is widened by dragging handles (text reflows and height auto adjusts).
1.3.2 = 1.3.1 if the object is widened by dragging handles (text reflows and height auto adjusts).

1.1.3 = 1.1.1 if the object is narrowed by dragging handles (text reflows and height auto adjusts).
1.2.3 = 1.2.1 if the object is narrowed by dragging handles (text reflows and height auto adjusts).
1.3.3 = 1.3.1 if the object is narrowed by dragging handles (text reflows and height auto adjusts).

1.4.1 = Shape snapping back to the default size (max height = auto height) when content deleted from 1.3.1.

1.5.1 = Shape snapping back (or having vertical resize locked from manual edit) so the max or minimum height = auto height) when corner or top/bottom handles attempt to increase/decrease the height of 1.3.2.

Notes:

- I am not sure whether to call this an OBJECT, SHAPE or STENCIL???

I am not a coder but copy and paste in code if given clear instructions.

I have tried this but got (a) unexpectant extra space beneath the text, (b) the formula being overriden when the the shape was manually resized and (c) did not work when grouping two boxes together: [How to have an `auto fit content` textbox in Visio 2013?](https://superuser.com/questions/844750/how-to-have-an-auto-fit-content-textbox-in-visio-2013)